# "failed to get context" error against real server, works fine with mockserver

Tags: odata, sapui5

Following the [ODATA V4 tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/bcdbde6911bd4fc68fd435cf8e306ed0) in step 2: app runs against mockserver, tips are given to run it against a real server. Used the existing index.html as test/mockServer.html and created a new index.html, pointing to ComponentSupport for oninit. Added cors-anywhere and adjusted the manifest. Works well, both mockserver and real.

That was in step 2 and the app worked fine also against a real server. Fast-forward to step 5 and I notice the app fails to load any data when running against a real server. [Long story short](https://github.com/AndreaBorgia-Abo/tutorial_openui5/commit/9d1d1f052b212138ae93b2629719edfb5333977b), the [backend](https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(id))/People?$count=true&$select=Age,FirstName,LastName,UserName&$skip=0&$top=10) is throwing an error, not even "count" together with "top" is accepted. I checked the [docs for ODATA](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#count), "count" does not seem to be an exclusive option.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the way ODATA works? I am especially puzzled by the fact that the mockserver runs fine.

EDIT: [created bugreport](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3041)

Comment: The docs you're using mention `People?$count=true`, in an SAP oData service that is just `People?$count` or `People/$count` depending on what you're after. Not sure if that has anything to do with your error though.

Comment: From what I see, it is possible to use both "People/$count=true" and "People/....../$count" Also, my changes made a mockserver-only tutorial into a dual real/mock setup, I did not change anything else.

Comment: In the cap/cds service I tried it on, the =true addition resulted in an error

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting! I'll wait a bit more for answers and comments and perhaps file a bug against the tutorial

Comment: It could be a bug in cap/cds since it’s new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in the [closing comment of my bugreport](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3041#issuecomment-707983527), Microsoft has confirmed the issue: "This was due to an error in the version of the OData WebAPI library we were using in the backing service. I have an update with various fixes, including updating to the latest WebAPI library that contains this fix, that I just haven't pushed out to production yet. Let me see when if I can get that deployed."